# CursorLoader + CursorAdapter + Regular DB updates = Gridview Flicker

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-cursoradapter, android-contentresolver, android-cursorloader

I have a custom image gallery app that stores the image data in a database.  The gallery is a `GridView` backed by `CursorAdapter`.

When first requesting an image decode `ContentResolver.update` updates the height, width, and orientation in a background thread.  Since many images are visible at a time the database updates are happening rapidly as a user scrolls which causes the backing `CursorLoader` to refresh the `GridView` rapidly which manifests itself as a rapid flicker.

Is it not possible to use `CursorLoader` and `CursorAdapter` if the underlying source can rapidly change, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

When there's a change to monitored data (selection, projection) within a database the `LoaderManager` simply supplies a new cursor.  As such, as far as the `CursorAdapter` is concerned it will have an entirely new datasource (`swapCursor`) on every update to the database:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
{
    mGalleryAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}
```

Therefore the ideal `CursorAdapter` attached to a dynamic `LoaderManager` will need to micro-manage view updates to ensure that it does not bother updating views that are *exactly* the same.  To do so (since my views are fairly complicated) I created a helper object to handle translations and comparisons between cursor and views (removed most views for the sake of brevity).

```
public static class GalleryItem
{
    private String name;
    private int  rotation;

    public static GalleryItem fromCursor(Context c, Cursor cursor)
    {
        GalleryItem item = new GalleryItem();
        item.rotation = ImageUtils.getRotation(cursor.getInt(Meta.ORIENTATION_COLUMN));
        item.name = cursor.getString(Meta.NAME_COLUMN);
        return item;
    }

    public static GalleryItem fromViewHolder(ViewHolder vh)
    {
        GalleryItem item = new GalleryItem();
        item.rotation = (int)vh.mImageView.getRotation();
        item.name = (String) vh.mFileName.getText();
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        GalleryItem compare = (GalleryItem) o;
        boolean sameRotation = rotation == compare.rotation;
        boolean sameName = name == null ? compare.name == null : name.equals(compare.name);

        return sameName && sameRotation;
    }
}
```

Then use this to check if you need to update anything in the view:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder vh, final int position, Cursor cursor)
    {
        GalleryItem galleryItem = GalleryItem.fromCursor(mContext, cursor);
        GalleryItem former = GalleryItem.fromViewHolder(vh);

        // If nothing has changed avoid refreshing.
        // The reason for this is that loaderManagers replace cursors meaning every change
        // will refresh the entire data source causing flickering
        if (former.equals(galleryItem))
            return;
...
```

**So long story short, with a dynamic `LoaderManager` you'll have to implement a way to skip recreating completely unchanged views.**